# close the opened window in javascript

Tags: javascript

Due to the security issue , I would like to create a javascript function for user to close the browser window , the function could close all the browser the user is using , for example ,  if the user use this function on chrome , then close all chrome browser , could how to write such javascript ? thanks

Comment: You can't close all the windows. You can only close those windows which were opened by javascript (using window.open)

Comment: @WraithNath not a dupe, OP wants to close windows that he did not open as well. While the part about closing the other windows is similar, the part about not being able to close windows you did not open is different.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - ok, not an exact duplicate, but it has the same answer you have given :)

Comment: thanks reply , if can not close it , could close the current window ( the window runs the close function ) ?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can only close windows you opened and/or have a reference to from your JavaScript code. Attempting to do so results in a JavaScript error.

If you *did* open the window you can close it with [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close) ([**fiddle with example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfbkp/))